# Ошибка при добавлении класса в виджет

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Доброго времени суток. Пишу виджет. При добавлении класса и компиляции выходит ниже описанная ошибка. Читал что это возможно при сборке файлов и компилятор(сборщик) попросту не видит и зависит ли это от этих вопросов что на картинке?

[image: вопросы]

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Forcast", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in TodayViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: из ошибки следует, что TodayVC ссылается на Forcast, который компилятор не видит. может он не добавлен в текущий таргет, может еще что.

Answer (score 1):

На правой панели в открытом m. файле есть "Target membership". Поставьте галочку в Forcast.m напротив имени вашего таргета "Today Extension".